# How to convert QList<T> to QVariant?

Tags: c++, qt, qlist, qvariant

I can't find a way to convert my `QList<T>` to a `QVariant`.

There's a **constructor** `QVariant(const QList<QVariant> &val)`, but no constructor for `QList<T>` , is it possible to convert directly a `QList<T>` ?

Comment: Assume that your T typename is included in QVariant union types (otherwise you cannot). why you don't convert every T object in QVariant, put all this converted in QList<QVariant> and finally convert it to QVariant ?

Comment: @requinham I was hoping there was something more simple ...

Answer (score 4):

Example

```
QList<int> ints{1,2,3};
QVariant var = QVariant::fromValue<QList<int>>(ints);
```

Comment: Qt Note: If you are working with custom types, you should use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() macro to register your custom type.